# Django calling an another function inside from a view function

Tags: python, django, django-views

The views.py somthing like this

```
def getFormValues(request):
if ('mobile_a' in request.GET and request.GET['mobile_a']) and ('mobile_b' in request.GET and request.GET['mobile_b']):
    mobile_a = request.GET['mobile_a']
    mobile_b =request.GET['mobile_b']
    # calling the mark calculation function
    return calculateMark(mobile_a, mobile_b)
else:
    message ='You submitted an empty form.'
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

Here I am calling a function(calculateMark) which will calculate a marking. In the end of the calculateMark function I have something like this

```
if (tech_mark_a == 0 and tech_mark_b == 0):
    mobile_a_infos = TechSpecificationAdd.objects.filter(tech_variables)
    return render_to_response('degrees_result.html', {'mobile_a': tech_mark_a, 'mobile_b': mobile_b}, mobile_a_infos)

elif (tech_mark_a > 0 and tech_mark_b > 0):
    return render_to_response('degrees_result.html', {'mobile_a': tech_mark_a, 'mobile_b': mobile_b})
```

The Problem is when I am submitting an empty form It's showing the message as getFormValues(). But when I submit something on the form it's showing an error The view **MarkCalculation.views.getFormValues didn't return an HttpResponse object.** 
How can I solve the problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your `calculateMark()` function so that it doesn't have any code paths that don't return a response. Also, consider converting the arguments to numbers first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please elaborate the procedure, what Should I do?

Comment: **HINT: `calculateMark(0, 25); calculateMark(-3, 4)`**

Comment: Thanks It's solved. I had a silly mistake inside the calculateMark() function.